# Apply CSS rule to all future elements

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a simple Chrome extension for personal use. I want to apply a CSS rule to all elements that match a class, even if they are rendered dynamically at some point after my extension's script is executed. 
How can I do this in RAW javascript?

Comment: What's wrong with adding a class to the CSS?

Comment: CSS will do just fine on this one

Answer (score 3):

CSS rules will match any current and future elements in your document. The style gets applied as the document changes.

[HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/) has a great article to give you a nice overview of [how browsers work](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/), including when and why layout and styling is applied.